# What exactly are the 'voids' in the Fringe parallel universe?

Tags: parallel-universe, fringe

From what I can tell the primary reason that the *other* parallel universe is seeking to destroy *our* universe is because they presume that the voids that appear there are being caused by this universe.

I get that the voids started occuring when Walter crossed over to get the other Peter, but what exactly is causing these voids?

Comment: I'd research the answer to this one, but I'm probably going to watch the series soon.

Comment: I've split this into two questions - here is the second one: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/fringe-what-is-the-amber-substance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The voids are micro-black holes (the amber is used to "seal" these).

Traveling between the two universes probably requires bending space (I assume some kind of inter-universe wormhole is created). 
It could be that these wormholes then pinch off into just a black hole, which then needs to be sealed.

Since travel between the two universes seems to have originated 'over here', we might deduce that creating a wormhole is more controlled, since we get to choose where we start. 
It looks like the other end of the wormhole might be more unstable, which would explain why the voids only occur 'over there', and not 'over here'.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield You are correct, the events at Reiden Lake poked the first hole between the universes and (as far as we know) started the instability.  But the source of the micro black holes is mostly unknown - the only time we see the cause of one, it's creating the same instabilities on our side.  (I forget the episode, but remember the old lady seeing her dead husband, and everyone thought her apartment building was haunted?)

Comment: Actually, it is not exactly the same thing. The voids are a result of instability in the fabric of the universes, whereas the other case you described where the old lady sees her dead husband is actually a case of quantum entanglement. It is the same phenomenon that makes the shape-shifters able to communicate to each universe via the typewriter. In one case the typewriter is the quantum entangled object, whereas in the other case it was the building that was entangled. These are not exactly related to the black holes, although they are caused by instabilities in the fabric of the universes.

Comment: @JNat I believe the conversation Over There right at the end of the episode confirmed it was the same type of instability that they usually see, whether it was micro black holes or not