# What is the amber substance?

Tags: fringe

Is there any indication what the 'amber substance' is in Fringe, or how it is able to counteract the voids that are created?

Note: This was originally part of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/fringe-what-exactly-are-the-voids-in-the-parallel-universe), but was split out into its own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A chemical substance called Amber 31422 was developed by Secretary Bishop in the parallel universe to contain micro-black-hole events causing devastating tears in the fabric of his universe. The alternate universe Fringe Division uses this technology to quarantine the damaging spatial rifts after damaging energy signatures are detected.
Amber 31422 is released in gaseous form, which later solidifies.
Check out http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Amber for Fringe-related questions!